# nth number in the Fibonacci sequence

Tags: java, while-loop

I do not know how to print, where in the fibonacci sequence the number is (nth number). The bold text is what I'm having trouble with and I have to use a while loop.

Please input a number for analysis >> 1
1 is a Fibonacci number **whose order in the sequence is both 2 and 3.**

Please input a number for analysis >> 56
55 is not a Fibonacci number. **However 56 is between 11 and 12.**

here is my code

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class While
{
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
System.out.println("Welcome to the Fibonacci Sequence Detector\n\n");
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);    
System.out.print("Please input a number for analysis: ");
int input = in.nextInt();

int fib = 0;
int fib1 = 1;
int n;
while(true)
{
    n=fib+fib1;
    if(input == fib1)
    {
        fib = -1;
        break;
    }
    if(input>fib1 && input < n)
    {
        break;
    }
    fib = fib1;
    fib1=n;
}
if (fib == -1 || input == 0)
    System.out.println(input+" is a Fibonacci number whose order in the sequence is " );
    else
    System.out.println(input+ " is not a Fibonacci number" );


} 
}
```

Comment: looks like a homework ;)

Comment: yeah im stuck on reading the fib. seq.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way I can think of is to have a counter variable that you increment every time through.

```
while(true) {
    count++;
...
}
...
System.out.println(input+" is a Fibonacci number whose order in the sequence is "+count);
```

As a side note, is there a reason you're using `while(true)`? Usually there's a way to track a condition where you want to STOP looping. (I was taught that `while(true)` isn't always wrong, but it usually is.) :)

Comment: I thought what ever is inside while loop has to be true?

Comment: how would I quit the program when the user inputs quite? 

`boolean on = true
 
while(on){
// prompt for user input
if(userInput.equals("quit")){
on = false;
}`

Comment: That's pretty much exactly how to quit when the user inputs 'quit'. Surround everything after the Scanner declaration in that `while(on)` loop and you should be golden.

Answer (score 0):

There is a closed form for the Fibonacci sequence, so it isn't necessary to search up to the number you are interested in. It is possible to directly calculate the n<sup>th</sup> Fibonacci number, and to find out the position of a given number in the sequence.

```
public class Fibi {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double root5 = Math.sqrt(5);
        double phi = (1.0 + root5) / 2.0;
        double log_phi = Math.log(phi);

        for (String s : args) {
            long fib = Long.parseLong(s);
            long n = (long) Math.floor(Math.log(fib * root5) / log_phi);
            long nth = Math.round(Math.pow(phi, n) / root5);
            long next = Math.round(Math.pow(phi, n+1) / root5);
            if (fib == nth) {
                System.out.printf("%d is a Fibonacci number whose order is %d.%n",
                    fib, n);
            } else if (fib == next) {
                System.out.printf("%d is a Fibonacci number whose order is %d.%n",
                    fib, n+1);
            } else {
                System.out.printf("%d is not a Fibonacci number. " +
                    "However, %d is between %d and %d.%n", fib, fib, n, n+1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you run this program with `java Fibi 102334155` it outputs:

```
102334155 is a Fibonacci number whose order is 40.
```

Note that I have not implemented `1`, which appears twice in the sequence, and can easily be handled as a special case, and I have changed slightly the numbering of the indices. You have 1 at positions 2 and 3, and 55 at position 11, which implies that your are considering 0 to be the first number in the Fibonacci sequence, where I have normally seen it defined as starting with `1 1`. However, that could be handled with a minor change.

Comment: thanks! I changed my code around and it works perfectly but I can't the program to quit when user inputs "quit" @DavidConrad